# Linking using OpenMp with ctypes

Tags: python, c, linux, ctypes, openmp

I have a c99 function that uses openmp, which works as expected. I also wrote a python interface using ctypes which causes the problem. Ctypes/python can not find the library for openmp. Here is the error message:

```
File "foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    foobar=cdll.LoadLibrary("./libfoo.so")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./libfoo.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel_end
```

And I use these cmds:

```
gcc -fPIC -std=c99 -lm -Wall -fopenmp -pedantic -c foo.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
python foo.py
```

I already googled and found a ''solution'' [online](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ctypes/month=20071001Blockquote), but I don't understand what is meant with:

> I suppose I should set restype on constructors to ctypes.c_void_p.
> And that I should set the corresponding  types in argtypes on called
> functions to ctypes.c_void_p.  Will this cause necessary conversions
> to take place? I'd like some confirmation that this is the right way
> to approach this situation.

What does the solution mean or do you know an other way?

**[update]**

So here is the correct cmd line options with the help from Iulian Şerbănoiu:

```
gcc -fPIC -std=c99 -lm -Wall -fopenmp -pedantic -c foo.c
gcc -shared -lgomp -lrt  -o libfoo.so foo.o
python foo.py
```

Comment: This is where I ask the dumb question of "Why aren't you linking against OpenMP?".

Comment: I thought -fopenmp links against OpenMP or did I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `-lgomp` option in order to link with openmp library. From [here](http://www.openmp.org/pipermail/omp/2006/000436.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `-fopenmp` flag also when linking:

```
gcc -shared -fopenmp -o libfoo.so foo.o
```